# Connect PHP With Portable MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, portable-database

Is it possible to connect PHP with portable MySQL file ?

Comment: If you're using sqlite, yes.

Comment: Obvious.. U just need to set the path in the config.php file if you are using a single file to connect to your database.. I always use config.php and put all the connection strings required..

Comment: Its possible, how ever I suggest you to search here or in GOOGLE how to do that..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002406/is-it-better-to-use-mysql-or-files-to-store-data/2002430#2002430 this can be helpful

Comment: you have to protect your file via .htaccess otherwise it could be downloaded

Answer (score 2):

Check out sqlite if you want a "file" database however , you shouldnt use it in production for your website if you aim at medium/high traffic , but for local testing it is ok.

Comment: I use MySQL Database...!!!

Comment: So what's your problem then ? stick to mysql which is a server. You can use mysql with ASP.NET too , can you put it in a file in the app folder ? no.

Comment: When I work on any existing project I have to export database from existing site and I have to import that database.
But if we keep database in application then no need to import or export...